# mmap fails for large buffers

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to do a simple mmap driver covering the very basics. More like a simple example driver. But I am trying to use a large chunk of memory allocated through kzalloc (102 pages rounded off to 100). I am not understanding why my mmap is unable to access the pages from user space. Why cant I access beyond 10-14 pages? Is it compulsory for our driver to manually handle page fauts?

## map_dev.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
//#include <asm-generic/io.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <asm/io.h>

//#define MEM_SIZE  409600
#define MEM_SIZE    4096
#define NPAGES      100
#ifndef VM_RESERVED
# define  VM_RESERVED   (VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_DONTDUMP)
#endif

static void *dmem;
static unsigned int *dmem_area;
static int in_use;

static int dmem_map(struct file *filp,  struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    long length = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    if(length > NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE)
        return -EIO;
    printk("%s: mapping\n", __func__);
    if(remap_pfn_range( vma,
                vma->vm_start,
                virt_to_phys((void *)dmem_area) >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                length, vma->vm_page_prot) < 0)
    {
        printk("%s: Error remap failed\n", __func__);
        return -EAGAIN;
    }
    printk("%s: mapping done\n", __func__);
    return 0;

}
static int mmap_dev_open(struct inode *inod, struct file *file)
{
    int i;
    printk("%s: open\n", __func__);
        if(in_use)
                return -EBUSY;
        in_use++;
    dmem = kzalloc((size_t) ((NPAGES + 2) * PAGE_SIZE), GFP_KERNEL);
    dmem_area = (int *)((((unsigned long)dmem) + PAGE_SIZE - 1) & PAGE_MASK);
    printk("%s: PAGE_SIZE = %lu\n", __func__, PAGE_SIZE);
    printk("%s: dmem = %lu\n", __func__, (unsigned long)(virt_to_page((unsigned long)dmem)));
    for(i = 0; i < NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE; i += PAGE_SIZE)
        SetPageReserved(virt_to_page(((unsigned long)dmem_area) + i));
    for(i = 0; i < NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE; i += PAGE_SIZE)
        printk("i= %d \t: Reserved: %lu dmem: 0x%x \n",
            i,
            (unsigned long)(virt_to_page(((unsigned long)dmem_area) + i)),
            (unsigned int)((unsigned long) dmem_area));
    printk("%s: Validating memory\n", __func__);
    printk("%s: Count size = %lu\n", __func__, (NPAGES - 1)*PAGE_SIZE);
    for(i=0;i < (NPAGES-1) * PAGE_SIZE; i++){
        dmem_area[i] = i;
        if ( (i%4096) == 0)
            printk("%s: checking page : %d\n",__func__, i/4096);
    }

    printk("%s: Final value of i = %d\n", __func__, i);
    dmem_area[0] = 0xFF00FF00;
        return 0;
}

static int mmap_dev_release(struct inode *inod, struct file *file)
{
        in_use = 0;
    //free_page((unsigned long) dmem);
    kfree(dmem);
        return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations mmap_dev_fops = {
    .owner          =       THIS_MODULE,
        .open           =       mmap_dev_open,
        .release        =       mmap_dev_release,
    .mmap       =   dmem_map,
};

static struct miscdevice mmap_dev_device = \
{
        .minor      =   MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
        .name       =   "mmap_dev",
        .fops       =   &mmap_dev_fops,
    .nodename   =   "mmap_dev",
    .mode       =   0666
};

module_driver(mmap_dev_device, misc_register, misc_deregister);

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Platform device for mmap_dev_driver");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_ALIAS("MMAP:DRV");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Preetam S Reddy <preetam@mistralsolutions.com>");
```

The above is the kernel driver.

The below file registers a device in kernel.

## map_device.c

```
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static struct platform_device mmap_pdev = {
    .name = "mmap_dev",
};

int __init pmod_init(void)
{
    platform_device_register(&mmap_pdev);
    return 0;
}
void __exit pmod_exit(void)
{
    platform_device_unregister(&mmap_pdev);

}

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Platform device for mmap driver");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_ALIAS("MMAP:DRV");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Preetam S Reddy <preetam@mistralsolutions.com>");
```

The below code is for the userspace app.

## mmap_example.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NPAGES  100
int main(void)
{
    int len = NPAGES * getpagesize();
    unsigned int *mm_addr;
    printf("page size = %d\n", getpagesize());
    printf("length = %d", len);
    int fd = open("/dev/mmap_dev", O_RDWR);
    getc(stdin);
    printf("Opening file...\n");
    printf("mmap ...\n");
    mm_addr = mmap(0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_LOCKED, fd, 0);
    if(mm_addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("mmap failed\n");
        perror("mmap");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("mmap complete. \n");
    getc(stdin);
    printf("data @[0] : 0x%x\n", mm_addr[0]);
    close(fd);
    #if 1
    printf("um-mmap ...\n");
    munmap(mm_addr, len);
    printf("umap... done\n");
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the main part of the kernel output:

```
[ 7782.754615] map_dev_open: open
[ 7782.754703] map_dev_open: PAGE_SIZE = 4096
[ 7782.754706] map_dev_open: dmem = 18446719884479594496
[ 7782.754711] i= 0     : Reserved: 18446719884479594496 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754714] i= 4096  : Reserved: 18446719884479594560 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754716] i= 8192  : Reserved: 18446719884479594624 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754719] i= 12288     : Reserved: 18446719884479594688 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754722] i= 16384     : Reserved: 18446719884479594752 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754725] i= 20480     : Reserved: 18446719884479594816 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754728] i= 24576     : Reserved: 18446719884479594880 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754731] i= 28672     : Reserved: 18446719884479594944 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754734] i= 32768     : Reserved: 18446719884479595008 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754736] i= 36864     : Reserved: 18446719884479595072 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754739] i= 40960     : Reserved: 18446719884479595136 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754742] i= 45056     : Reserved: 18446719884479595200 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754745] i= 49152     : Reserved: 18446719884479595264 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754748] i= 53248     : Reserved: 18446719884479595328 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754751] i= 57344     : Reserved: 18446719884479595392 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754753] i= 61440     : Reserved: 18446719884479595456 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754756] i= 65536     : Reserved: 18446719884479595520 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754759] i= 69632     : Reserved: 18446719884479595584 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754762] i= 73728     : Reserved: 18446719884479595648 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754765] i= 77824     : Reserved: 18446719884479595712 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754768] i= 81920     : Reserved: 18446719884479595776 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754770] i= 86016     : Reserved: 18446719884479595840 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754773] i= 90112     : Reserved: 18446719884479595904 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754776] i= 94208     : Reserved: 18446719884479595968 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754779] i= 98304     : Reserved: 18446719884479596032 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754782] i= 102400    : Reserved: 18446719884479596096 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754784] i= 106496    : Reserved: 18446719884479596160 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754787] i= 110592    : Reserved: 18446719884479596224 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754790] i= 114688    : Reserved: 18446719884479596288 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754793] i= 118784    : Reserved: 18446719884479596352 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754796] i= 122880    : Reserved: 18446719884479596416 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754798] i= 126976    : Reserved: 18446719884479596480 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754801] i= 131072    : Reserved: 18446719884479596544 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754804] i= 135168    : Reserved: 18446719884479596608 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754807] i= 139264    : Reserved: 18446719884479596672 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754810] i= 143360    : Reserved: 18446719884479596736 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754812] i= 147456    : Reserved: 18446719884479596800 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754815] i= 151552    : Reserved: 18446719884479596864 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754818] i= 155648    : Reserved: 18446719884479596928 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754821] i= 159744    : Reserved: 18446719884479596992 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754824] i= 163840    : Reserved: 18446719884479597056 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754826] i= 167936    : Reserved: 18446719884479597120 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754829] i= 172032    : Reserved: 18446719884479597184 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754832] i= 176128    : Reserved: 18446719884479597248 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754835] i= 180224    : Reserved: 18446719884479597312 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754837] i= 184320    : Reserved: 18446719884479597376 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754840] i= 188416    : Reserved: 18446719884479597440 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754843] i= 192512    : Reserved: 18446719884479597504 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754846] i= 196608    : Reserved: 18446719884479597568 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754849] i= 200704    : Reserved: 18446719884479597632 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754851] i= 204800    : Reserved: 18446719884479597696 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754854] i= 208896    : Reserved: 18446719884479597760 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754857] i= 212992    : Reserved: 18446719884479597824 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754860] i= 217088    : Reserved: 18446719884479597888 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754863] i= 221184    : Reserved: 18446719884479597952 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754865] i= 225280    : Reserved: 18446719884479598016 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754868] i= 229376    : Reserved: 18446719884479598080 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754871] i= 233472    : Reserved: 18446719884479598144 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754874] i= 237568    : Reserved: 18446719884479598208 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754877] i= 241664    : Reserved: 18446719884479598272 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754879] i= 245760    : Reserved: 18446719884479598336 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754882] i= 249856    : Reserved: 18446719884479598400 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754885] i= 253952    : Reserved: 18446719884479598464 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754888] i= 258048    : Reserved: 18446719884479598528 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754891] i= 262144    : Reserved: 18446719884479598592 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754893] i= 266240    : Reserved: 18446719884479598656 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754896] i= 270336    : Reserved: 18446719884479598720 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754899] i= 274432    : Reserved: 18446719884479598784 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754902] i= 278528    : Reserved: 18446719884479598848 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754905] i= 282624    : Reserved: 18446719884479598912 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754908] i= 286720    : Reserved: 18446719884479598976 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754910] i= 290816    : Reserved: 18446719884479599040 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754913] i= 294912    : Reserved: 18446719884479599104 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754916] i= 299008    : Reserved: 18446719884479599168 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754919] i= 303104    : Reserved: 18446719884479599232 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754922] i= 307200    : Reserved: 18446719884479599296 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754924] i= 311296    : Reserved: 18446719884479599360 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754927] i= 315392    : Reserved: 18446719884479599424 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754930] i= 319488    : Reserved: 18446719884479599488 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754933] i= 323584    : Reserved: 18446719884479599552 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754936] i= 327680    : Reserved: 18446719884479599616 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754938] i= 331776    : Reserved: 18446719884479599680 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754941] i= 335872    : Reserved: 18446719884479599744 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754944] i= 339968    : Reserved: 18446719884479599808 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754947] i= 344064    : Reserved: 18446719884479599872 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754950] i= 348160    : Reserved: 18446719884479599936 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754952] i= 352256    : Reserved: 18446719884479600000 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754955] i= 356352    : Reserved: 18446719884479600064 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754958] i= 360448    : Reserved: 18446719884479600128 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754961] i= 364544    : Reserved: 18446719884479600192 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754963] i= 368640    : Reserved: 18446719884479600256 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754966] i= 372736    : Reserved: 18446719884479600320 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754969] i= 376832    : Reserved: 18446719884479600384 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754972] i= 380928    : Reserved: 18446719884479600448 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754975] i= 385024    : Reserved: 18446719884479600512 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754977] i= 389120    : Reserved: 18446719884479600576 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754980] i= 393216    : Reserved: 18446719884479600640 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754983] i= 397312    : Reserved: 18446719884479600704 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754986] i= 401408    : Reserved: 18446719884479600768 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754989] i= 405504    : Reserved: 18446719884479600832 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 8304.656599] systemd-hostnamed[6482]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 8407.896365] BUG: Bad page state: 40 messages suppressed
[ 8407.896373] BUG: Bad page state in process a.out  pfn:62a00
[ 8407.896379] page:ffffea00018a8000 count:0 mapcount:0 mapping:          (null) index:0x0
[ 8407.896381] page flags: 0x1ffff0000004400(reserved|head)
[ 8407.896388] Modules linked in: map_dev(OF) map_device(OF) rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc arc4 brcmsmac cordic brcmutil btusb intel_powerclamp b43 bluetooth coretemp kvm_intel kvm mac80211 i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_hdmi cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo snd_hda_intel ssb snd_hda_codec ghash_clmulni_intel drm_kms_helper snd_hwdep aesni_intel snd_pcm videobuf2_vmalloc snd_page_alloc aes_x86_64 drm acer_wmi videobuf2_memops lrw snd_seq_midi i2c_algo_bit gf128mul parport_pc glue_helper snd_seq_midi_event sparse_keymap ppdev videobuf2_core ablk_helper snd_rawmidi cryptd joydev videodev serio_raw lp bcma snd_seq wmi mei_me mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_ips soundcore mac_hid lpc_ich video parport psmouse tg3 ahci ptp libahci pps_core [last unloaded: map_dev]
[ 8407.896482] CPU: 1 PID: 6444 Comm: a.out Tainted: GF   B      O 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu
[ 8407.896485] Hardware name: Acer            TravelMate 4740                /TravelMate 4740                , BIOS V1.12           05/04/2010
```

Comment: Did your `printk`s fire? What did they show? What was `errno` after your call to `mmap` failed?

Comment: I got the printks. The kernel dumped addresses which are 64 bytes apart. They should actually be 4096 bytes apart. I am confused.

Comment: What addresses are 64 bytes apart? Please show the actual output

Comment: how do I add a file here?

Comment: Can't you just edit your question? If not, link to pastebin or something, and someone will edit it in for you.

Comment: The log file is pretty big. Thats why I dont want to put it with the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55451/discussion-between-preetam-and-useless).

Comment: I have added print log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I *think* the printk which you're worried about is this one:

```
[ 7782.754711] i= 0     : Reserved: 18446719884479594496 dmem: 0x62a00000 
[ 7782.754714] i= 4096  : Reserved: 18446719884479594560 dmem: 0x62a00000
```

coming from here:

```
for(i = 0; i < NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE; i += PAGE_SIZE)
    printk("i= %d \t: Reserved: %lu dmem: 0x%x \n",
        i,
        (unsigned long)(virt_to_page(((unsigned long)dmem_area) + i)),
        (unsigned int)((unsigned long) dmem_area));
```

because `i` is increasing by 4096 each time, but the page frame number (from `virt_to_page`) isn't.  If you look at the definition of `virt_to_page`, you'll see that it converts the virtual address argument to physical address, and then shifts that right by `PAGE_SHIFT` bits. So, the PFN you log *must* increase by less than `i`.

What is `PAGE_SHIFT` on your system?  If it is `6`, then `4096 >> 6 == 64` and your confusion is explained.

---

Now, that's the issue you mentioned in comments. Your original question was

> I am not understanding why my mmap is unable to access the pages from user space. Why cant I access beyond 10-14 pages?

but you haven't said what the symptoms are. When you try to access the 15th page, what happens?

Well, in the userspace you are accessing it as int. So you will be accessing 4 bytes at a time so you have adjust the for loop for that.
Also the addresses you get is the page frame number. Not the full byte address.

Comment: I think your are right on this one. But I also made a mistake in my app. I am allocating 100 pages in bytes. But accessing them in words. So I will get a little less than 25% in words. I got access to almost all the memory when I change int *mm_addr to char *mm_addr.

Comment: But there is still some confusion on the addresses returned. Kzallloc is supposed to return physically contiguous memory.  I am also doing a virt_to_page translation before printing. So shouldnt I actually get continuous page addresses starting from a page aligned address ?

Comment: Are you telling me that there are lower bits in the address which are not being shown. Giving me only the page addresses, but then, PAGE_SHIFT must be 11 for a 32 bit system.

Comment: Yes, virt_to_page gives a page frame number, _not_ an address. Did you mean to use virt_to_phys?

Comment: I thought it would give the address of first byte of the page. Now I see.